# How to make a box with user options in facebook open graph

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have an online magazine with news articles and i want to make an open graph action that everytime a user reads an article a story to post in his timeline.
I have all the nececery open graph tags in my urls and a login button with **publish_actions** scope.
I'm one step away from submitting the action for approval but i still cant figure out one thing.

The facebook's documentation says that i need to give users an option to stop auto publishing or remove the app etc. something like the image in the middle of this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read . 
I saw it also on yahoo and its exacly the same.

**How can i make something like this in my site? The code is ready somewhere or i have to write it myself?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The permission remove, or just a switch to stop publish of action and the delete article functions will have to be developed by you.

> I am working on the same things for my app.
>
> 1. creating user CP control panel containing, revoke perms buttons.
> 2. a user CP to swich publishing on and off, via true/false in mysql
> 3. an array of app activities with delete buttons.